# Annotating a push rpc call in protocol buffers

Tags: c++, rpc, protocol-buffers

How do I define a push only rpc call in the protocol buffers language ? The syntax shown in the service definition subsection only shows a general request -> returns pair.

One solution I can think of is to have a sentinel message such as 'ReturnsNothing' and look for that in my rpc generation program.

I am hoping there is a better way of doing this, perhaps there is an undocumented solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just introduce and use an `Empty` message type:

```
message Empty
{
}

service MyService
{
  rpc Search (MyRequest) returns (Empty);
}
```

(Not sure if you meant that same thing with your ReturnsNothing message).

Comment: Yes it is the same thing I mentioned, ReturnsNothing :D

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, there's nothing wrong with an empty type, or a unit type as some people call them.